# initialise 2d array from multiple text files c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm currently building a c# console application to display, search and sort weather data over 80 years. To do so, I'm implementing a 2d array to contain the data of the years, months, sun, rain, air frost, and max & min temperatures (which are stored in .txt files), like so:

```
string[,] Ws1Data = new string[lineCount,7]{
            File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\Year.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\Month.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_Sun.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_Rain.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_AF.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_TMin.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_TMax.txt"),
        };
```

However, when I compile the code I get the following errors:

```
program.cs(66,35): error CS0150: A constant value is expected
program.cs(67,5): error CS0846: A nested array initializer is expected
```

Can someone please explain these errors and how I would go about implementing this 2d array efficiently, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A constant value is expected when initialize an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594314/a-constant-value-is-expected-when-initialize-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only initialize 2 dimensional array with constants, like this:

```
string[,] Ws1Data = new string[2, 7]
{
    { "3", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7" },
    { "3", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7" },
};
```

I think in your case you are better off using jagged arrays. Do it like this:

```
string[][] Ws1Data = new []
{
    File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\Year.txt"),
    File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\Month.txt"),
    File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_Sun.txt"),
    File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_Rain.txt"),
    File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_AF.txt"),
    File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_TMin.txt"),
    File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_TMax.txt"),
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the first dimension of the multidimensional array has to be fixed.
Try something like this:

```
    string[][] Ws1Data = new string[8][];

    Ws1Data[0] = File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\Year.txt");

    Ws1Data[1] = File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\Year.txt");

    Ws1Data[2] = File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\Month.txt");

    Ws1Data[3] = File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_Sun.txt");

    Ws1Data[4] = File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_Rain.txt");

    Ws1Data[5] = File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_AF.txt");

    Ws1Data[6] = File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_TMin.txt");

    Ws1Data[7] = File.ReadAllLines(@"CMP1124M_Weather_Data\WS1_TMax.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Will this work instead? (I changed to jagged array instead of multidimensional)